# How to print out the odd index elements from a two dimensional array (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

For any given dimension (here I just set it to 8 to make it easy) I want to print out the letters with odd indexes. So I am trying to get an output like: B D F H... and other letters depending on the dimension). I put a while loop to make the row 0 since I only want to print out the the odd letters on the first row and then inside the while loop I added a for loop to print out the columns (letters) with odd n. However I am getting a not an error:

```
error: not a statement
    for (n = 1; n<dimension; n +2){
                               ^
```

I am also unsure of where to put the loops to print out the odd letters. 
This is my code so far:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dimension = 8; // normally any given dimension (int dimension = Integer.parseInt(args[0]))
    int n = dimension - 1;
    int m = dimension -1;
    char [] alphabet = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    int [] nums = new int [dimension];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i ++) {
      nums [i] = i + 1;
    }
    int [] [] position = new int [dimension] [dimension];
    for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row ++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col ++) {
        position [row] [col] = alphabet[col] + nums[row];
      }
  }
  char p = (char)(position[m][n] - nums[n]);
  while (m == 0) {
    for (n = 1; n<dimension; n +2){
      System.out.println(p);                     //odd letters on the first row
    }
  }
}
}
```

Edit: the program is compiling but the loop is not working so I am not getting any output. How can I fix it?

Comment: should be `n+=2`

Comment: `n=n+2` will work as well.

Comment: Also for readability and consistency please put one space around operators such as `<` and `+` and no space between `i` and `++`, and no space between `num` and `[]`. Look at other code in the same language on the Internet to get an idea of some styles people generally use and find acceptable rather than roll your own. If everyone sticks to clean and consistent styling it makes it easier to read code and find and fix bugs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple syntax error.

```
for (n = 1; n<dimension; n +2){
```

Should be:

```
for (n = 1; n<dimension; n += 2){
```

The final part of the `for` statement is an operation that can be used to change the iterator (or do other operations).  If you consider the following line of code:

```
n +2;
```

This is not a valid statement by itself.  However, the following statement *is valid*:

```
n += 2;
```

Comment: There is a close vote for questions with a typo. You should use that.

Comment: It is compiling now but there is no output :/ Should I put the for loop inside the other for loops?